# What's the reason of disappearing of information on project's natures?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, pydev

I'm seeing strange behavior in Eclipse (I'm using INDIGO, Version: 3.7.1, Build id: M20110909-1335). Information on project's natures (Project/Properties/Project Natures) is not always visible. I can't find any pattern when it's visible and when it's not. I'm observing this for C/C++ nature (provided by CTD) as well as for Python nature (provided by PyDev). I know a project has appropriate nature because for example in project's properties there are entries specific to that nature (like *C/C++ Build* or *PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar*)

What's the reason of this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I know that sometimes the place that'll show the properties page may customize it, so, depending on the place (i.e.: project explorer, pydev package explorer or simply using it in the menu project > properties) may yield different results.

So, probably if you use it from the menu bar: project > properties (while having the proper project selected) should work always the same way...